# import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider; failing

Tags: java, eclipse, jax-ws, cisco-axl

I am a newbie to eclipse, java, and axl.
I am trying to do the demo project shown on this vid: https://d1nmyq4gcgsfi5.cloudfront.net/images/axl/axl-vid-outline.mp4

you can see some of the code starting at min 9:03

I think this link is also part - the link to the video at this link is broken so I had to search for the video: https://developer.cisco.com/docs/axl/#!javajax-ws-quickstart/java-jax-ws-quickstart

Im running eclipse Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) Build id: 20190917-1200
and jdk 12.0.2 and jre 6

Ive was careful to follow the steps in the video - including downloading copying the schema in, and using wsimport to import the classes.

```
package com.cisco.axl.demo;


import com.cisco.axlapiservice.AXLAPIService;
import com.cisco.axlapiservice.AXLPort;
import com.cisco.axl.api._10.*;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;


/**
* Makes the getPhone request and displays some of the fields that are returned.
 */
private void getPhone() {

// Instantiate the wsimport generated AXL API Service client --
// see the wsimport comments in the class javadocs above
AXLAPIService axlService = new AXLAPIService();
AXLPort axlPort = axlService.getAXLPort();


// Set the URL, user, and password on the JAX-WS client
String validatorUrl = "https://"
    + Demo.ucHost
    + ":8443/axl/";


((BindingProvider) axlPort).getRequestContext().put(
    BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, validatorUrl);
((BindingProvider) axlPort).getRequestContext().put(
    BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, Demo.ucAdmin);
...
```

The problem is Im getting an error on the import last import command (in the video its the first import - I tried moving it in case it was a dependence thing)

I get a red x beside the line number and the words 'javax.xml.ws' are underlined in red. When I mouse over them I see the msg "The import javax.xml.ws cannot be resolved"

the program shows other errors as well but with one of the imports failing I presume that is normal.
I presume this is something I did or didnt do but even tho Ive searched on google, I cant really figure out what to do.

Can anyone jumpstart me?

Comment: The `javax.xml.ws` package was deprecated in JDK9 and removed in later releases. https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320

Comment: Thanks Greg, I downloaded JDK9 and figured out how to get javax.xml.ws into the project and that resolved the specified problem